# How to use Euclidean Distance to calculate similarity values for the three pairs of documents

Tags: information-retrieval, euclidean-distance

## I am trying to work on this question however I am not sure how to use the Euclidean equation to find the solution.

Question:

Following are keywords, frequencies, and token counts from 3 other
documents.

Doc 4 – tablet: 7; memory: 5; apps: 8; sluggish: 5

Doc 5 – memory: 4; performance: 6; playbook: 8; apps: 6

Doc 6 –tablet: 6; performance: 3; playbook: 7; sluggish: 3

Token counts: Doc 4: 55 Doc 5: 60 Doc 6: 65

(i) Use Euclidean Distance to calculate similarity values for the three pairs of
    documents (4,5), (4,6), (5,6) with relative frequency values. State the
    distance for each pair to 4 decimal places (4 d.p.).

---

I have tried to use the Euclidean Distance formula with the given pairs of documents to find the distance for each pair.

This is the equation that i have tried to use:

### dist((x, y), (a, b)) = √(x - a)² + (y - b)²

According to the solutions this is what the answer should be:

Euclidean D4,D5 = 0.2343 to 4.d.p

Euclidean D5,D6 = 0.1693 to 4.d.p

Euclidean D4,D6 = 0.2153 to 4.d.p

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please add what you've tried. also add question itself - not its image. otherwise this thread could be flagged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should make your document-term matrix based on your term-frequency. Term-frequency of a term means the number of times that term is repeated in a document divided by number of tokens document has. So we just made the below table:
[image]

As you mentioned the distance formula yourself I will just calculate the distance between document 4 and 5 as an example.

d(Document4,Document5) = [(7/55-0)^2 + (5/55-4/60)^2 + (8/55-6/60)^2 + (5/55-0)^2 + (0-6/60)^2 + (0-8/60)^2]^(1/2) = 0.23428614982 which is rounded to 0.2343.

Comment: should term frequency necessarily be divided by number of tokens ?

Comment: If you want to calculate the frequency, yes it is necessary! If you don't divide it by the number of tokens, you will have the number of term occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

The `Euclidean distance` is a popular heuristic and the formula is as follows:

Suppose you have 2 points `(a1,b1)` and `(a2,b2)`, then the `Euclidean distance` between these points is given as: `SquareRoot( (a2-a1)^2 + (b2-b1)^2 )`.

In your case,

```
Doc 4 - (7,5,8,5)
Doc 5 - (4,6,8,6)
```

So the formula to apply would be,

```
SquareRoot( (a2-a1)^2 + (b2-b1)^2 + (c2-c1)^2 + (d2-d1)^2 ).
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried to use the equation that you provided however I could not get the correct solutions.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance)

The Euclidean distance between points p and q is the length of the line segment connecting them **(pq)**.

In Cartesian coordinates, if p = (p1, p2,..., pn) and q = (q1, q2,..., qn) are two points in Euclidean n-space, then the distance (d) from p to q, or from q to p is given by the Pythagorean formula:

```
d(p ,q) = d (q ,p) = [(p1-q1)^2  + (p1-q1)^2 + ... (pn-qn)^2]^(1/2)
```

Let's normalize the given like this.

```
Doc 4 – tablet: 7, memory: 5, apps: 8, sluggish: 5, playbook: 0,  performance: 0
Doc 5 – tablet: 0, memory: 4, apps: 6, sluggish: 0, playbook: 8, performance: 6 
Doc 6 – tablet: 6, memory: 0, apps:0, sluggish: 3, playbook: 7, performance: 3
```

then according to above formula,

```
D(Doc4, Doc5) = [(7-0)^2 + (5-4)^2 + (8-6)^2 + (5-0)^2 + (8-0)^2 + (0-0)^2]^(1/2) = [49+1+4+25+64]^(1/2) ~= 11.96
```

You can calculate the other two pairs as I've done.

If needed let me know, thus I add a sample snippet to calculate this programmatically.

Comment: should term frequency be divided by number of tokens or not? and what is the difference then?